# When does UIWebView start recognising Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, xcode, uiwebview

```
// MARK: - UIWebViewDelegate
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    let initResponse =  self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("initialize('','','',\(isPreview))")

    if (initResponse != "") {
      isLoaded = true

    }

    println("\(viewType) initResponse \(initResponse)")
}
```

In my program, I am attempting to initialise UIWebView by calling a Javascript function. UIWebView is loaded with a local template file.

Apparently, the webview still does not respond to my javascript command even though `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called.

Therefore, I think there is another moment when web view can actually start accept Javascript calls. In my opinion, it is when `document` is ready for my locally loaded html file.

But then, how do I know when my UIWebview is ready to receive Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS/UIWebView, please have a try on this

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (![[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"])
        return;
    // Now it's ready
}
```

---

and for OS X, this one [webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) is what you want.

Comment: I think this is for OSX